# How do I make the FreeOffice interface look like the official screenshots?

Tags: 18.04, themes, gui, interface, scrollbar

On my Ubuntu Mate 18.04, the [FreeOffice](https://www.freeoffice.com/) interface (mainly the scrollbars) is somewhat Windows-y/Wine-y.

[image: FreeOffice with bad scrollbars]

How do I make it look like the official screenshots?

[image: FreeOffice with good scrollbars]

Comment: Note that I'm not talking about the color of the window, but the "structure" of scrollbars and drop-downs.

Comment: What is FreeOffice? Where did you got it?

Comment: @N0rbert, FreeOffice ( https://www.freeoffice.com/ ) is a free German office suite from Softmaker, derived from their paid version Softmaker Office

Comment: I'm not comfortable to use WPS Office anymore, because of the Chinese government. For this reason, I'm migrating to FreeOffice.

Comment: I posted an answer below. I do not see any issues with default installation of SoftMaker office on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS using default settings. The [comparison](https://www.softmaker.com/en/comparison-freeoffice-softmaker-office) from softmaker site says that its functionality is very poor for free version. You may want to try default LibreOffice (it is free and it is available in Ubuntu repositories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SoftMaker FreeOffice 2018 we need to do the following - select Ribbon interface on first launch

[image: selecting Ribbon]

or

> You can change the design of the user interface at any time the Options dialog ("Appearance" tab).

and then you will get the needed look and feel:

[image: TextMaker]